# BS Typeahead doesn't show results

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead

i have this problem with Bootstrap Typeahead.

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Recipients</label>
    <input id="recipients" name="recipients" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        class="form-control" 
        data-role="tagsinput">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#recipients').tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: false,
    trimValue: true,
    confirmKeys: [13, 44],
    typeahead: {
        source: function(queryForHints) {
            if (queryForHints.length < 4)
                return '';
            var parameters = {
                'queryForHints': queryForHints
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/xxxx/xxxx",
                data: parameters,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    return (data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("error for xxxxx/xxxxx");
                },
                async: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

After Ajax call I get this array:

```
[{
    "value": "+393334029137",
    "text": "Dean Leandra (+393334029137)"
}, {
    "value": "+393333419836",
    "text": "Alfonso Erasmus (+393333419836)"
}, {
    "value": "+393173833341",
    "text": "Travis Aquila (+393173833341)"
}, {
    "value": "+393334998841",
    "text": "Conan Preston (+393334998841)"
}]
```

The problem is: *I see nothing :( nothing appears. typeahead doesn't work.*

In the console, I get this error

> bootstrap-tagsinput.js:331 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'success' of undefined

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: What is null in your AJAX call array? Typo?

Comment: Now i resolved the problem suggested by you...now returned from ajax call i have:

[{
    "value": "+393334029137",
    "text": "Dean Leandra (+393334029137)"
}, {
    "value": "+393333419836",
    "text": "Alfonso Erasmus (+393333419836)"
}, {
    "value": "+393173833341",
    "text": "Travis Aquila (+393173833341)"
}, {
    "value": "+393334998841",
    "text": "Conan Preston (+393334998841)"
}]

Comment: help us to help you. you need to be clear on 3 things. 1. which version of bootstrap are you using. 2. which plugin are you using 3. is there a null after the array in the response from ajax call

Comment: is the issue fixed?

Comment: only in returning data from ajax, but i don't see anything in typeahead...
I'm using BS 3, Bootstrap 3 Typeahed last version..Yes i resolved the "null" problem after ajax call..

Comment: the error is on this row (of bs typeahead.js):
if ($.isFunction(data.success)) {
              // support for Angular callbacks
              data.success(processItems);

Comment: can you help me? i need to resolve this..please take 5 minutes for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function(data) {
  var sourceData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       sourceData.push(data[i].text);
    }
 return (sourceData);
```

What you have from your JSON response is an object array. You want to see `text` as a suggestion I assumed. So you need to get `text` from your object because typeahead source expects a string array. Push `text` values into another string array and return it. I haven't tested the code yet but it should work for you.

Another issue you have is that you are making an AJAX call which is async. That's why you have undefined from success.